# How to make 'TryCompile' work with yacc source files in Scons 4.x?

Tags: bison, scons

I have the following little test script in [SCons](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#configure_contexts) that works file with SCons 3.1.2, but fails with SCons 4.2.0. Can anyone suggest a good workaround?

```
env = Environment(tools = ['default','yacc','lex','swig'])

yacc_test_text = """
%{
#include <stdio.h>

/* MSVC++ needs this before it can swallow Bison output */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# define __STDC__
#endif
%}
%token MSG
%start ROOT
%%
ROOT:
    MSG { printf("HELLO"); } 
    ;
%%
"""

def CheckYacc(context):
    context.Message("Checking for Yacc ('%s')... " % context.env.get('YACC'))
    is_ok = context.TryCompile(yacc_test_text,".y")
    context.Result(is_ok)
    return is_ok
    
conf = Configure(env, custom_tests = {'CheckYacc' : CheckYacc})

conf.env['HAVE_YACC'] = True
if not conf.CheckYacc():
    conf.env['HAVE_YACC'] = False

conf.Finish()

if env['HAVE_YACC']:
    print("yacc is ok")
else:
    print("yacc is borken")
```

The output in SCons 3.1.1:

```
john@ovo:~/Desktop/test1$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for Yacc ('bison')... yes
yacc is ok
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

whereas for SCons 4.2.0, I get:

```
john@ovo:~/Desktop/test1$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: *** While building `['.sconf_temp/conftest_dd0e1c3dfab0803d28d6c748a4e13339_0SConfActionsContentDummyTarget']' from `['.sconf_temp/conftest_dd0e1c3dfab0803d28d6c748a4e13339_0.y']': Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.y'.  Expected a suffix in this list: ['.c', '.m', '.cpp', '.cc', '.cxx', '.c++', '.C++', '.mm', '.C', '.f', '.for', '.ftn', '.fpp', '.FPP', '.F', '.FOR', '.FTN', '.f77', '.F77', '.f90', '.F90', '.f95', '.F95', '.f03', '.F03', '.f08', '.F08', '.s', '.asm', '.ASM', '.spp', '.SPP', '.sx', '.S', '.d'].
File "/home/john/Desktop/test1/SConstruct", line 23, in CheckYacc
```

Comment: Where are your bison, lex, python, swig tools installed? (path). How were they installed? (msys, chocolatey, cygwin, etc?)

Comment: Post your config.log please

Comment: entire config.log is `file /home/john/Desktop/test1/SConstruct,line 31:
        Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for Yacc ('bison')...` (it just stops there)

Comment: this is all running on Ubuntu 20.04, with scons installed using 'pip install scons' (for the latest version, 4.2.0) or 'apt install sscons' (for versions 3.1.2)

Comment: bison is definitely being found, but for some reason the .y extension is no longer appearing in the list of extensions that TryCompile can access. Similarly .l isn't there any more.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues/3998

Comment: for those who are curious, this is a real bug in recent scons, and can be followed in the issue tracker.

Comment: @jdpipe - (removed my incorrect comment above ). This has to do with the requested builder Object() not having rules to translate .y -> .o,  which it shouldn't.   This only comes into play in newer SCons' because we try to ensure unique temp file names for config steps using the signature of the action used to build such.